# Proofs about a group property

Tags: proof-verification, logic

I have a set $B$,and for $b$ belonging to $B$,there exists a reverse $b$.
Is it enough if I prove this to be true for $1$ element of the set, then it must be true for the whole set of $B$, or must I prove this property $\forall x$ that belong to $B$.

Comment: This is not clear.  If you need to show a property holds for every element in some set, then that's what you need to show.  In general, it would not be enough to check one element.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Yes that is what i was asking.Thanks

Comment: Well, just think about it in common sense terms...If I assert that every shirt in my closet is yellow, it would not suffice to check one shirt and confirm that it is yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show that $B$ is a group, you need to show that **every** element of $B$ has an inverse.
You need to be able to calculate with any group element, so every element must have the basic properties given in the group axioms.